# When will the next 'Super Blue Blood Moon' occur?

Tags: the-moon

I missed the sight yesterday (1 feb 2018) because I live right in the region where the sight was not visible. So when will the next Super Blue Blood Moon occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for the perfect 'Super Blue Blood Moon', then, according to [this article](https://www.space.com/39557-next-blood-moon-eclipses-2018-2019.html) (assuming you live in the US):

> The next Super Blue Blood Moon won't happen until **Jan. 31, 2037**, and it will be visible in North America, Europe, Asia, Australia and parts of Africa.

However, if a Super Blood Moon is enough for you, you can see the next one on **Jan. 21, 2019**.